# Why com.sun.management.ThreadMXBean not functioning on Ant?

Tags: java, ant, junit

I have a test case which requires  com.sun.management.ThreadMXBean, to retrieve thread info. When I run this test case on eclipse it works but when I run from ant - junit task. it throws the following..

Here's my code snippet, How can get it working in ant ? Thanks.

 `ThreadMXBean threadMXBean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
com.sun.management.ThreadMXBean comSunThreadMXBean = (com.sun.management.ThreadMXBean)threadMXBean;`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with adding fork=true